# add RSS button in wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress blog on my website. But I've created my own page that pulls information from the database using the_post() loop and functions like the_author() and the_content() etc.

I want to know how to add an RSS button on my website.

So I need all my posts to be automatically converted to RSS, and then a button that users can click on and they subscribe to that feed.

I no nothing about RSS, I've researched and researched and tried multiple things. I know RSS is supposed to be simple but I just don't understand it.

All I know is that I need my posts to be converted into an RSS feed, and a button that lets users subscribe!

I know that the WordPress dashboard has RSS widgets etc., but as I said I have a separate page outside of the WordPress folder that pulls info from the database, the the widget wouldn't be useful. Unless you can specify widgets on completely separate pages!

Comment: Ive just found out that wordpress already has an automatic rss feed found in the www.example.com/wordpress-folder/wp-rss.php But now how do i creat a subscribe button with this url?

Comment: I am also confused by exactly the same point as OP. If I add a link to the RSS feed, won't this just take users to the XML page? How do they actually subscribe? Or is this something that happens automatically if they have a feedburner configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress automatically adds new posts to RSS feed. Usualy the address is http://blogurl.com/feed

You just have to create a ink to this URL.

```
<a href="http://blogurl.com/feed">**Subscribe**</a>
```

If you need more fancy RSS feeds and tracking then check out http://feedburner.com

Comment: adding this link just takes the users to the xml page?

Comment: Which Browser? RSS feed is an xml file and browsers detect it and usualy shows RSS reader options.